# How to search contact using phone number through generic inquiry

Tags: acumatica

I'm trying to use Generic Inquiry to search phone number in contact table. To do an exactly match is simple, however, since phone number in database could be any format, for example, "001-1234-567" could be "001 1234 567" or "0011234567", or "001-1234-567 ext 123", so if I want to get all of records with any of phone number above through matching "0011234567", I don't see any way in GI to be able to do it.

Does anybody know if there is a way to get around this?

By the way, I'm working on a project in that we need to pass customer info automatically from our e-commerce to Acumatica through web service API and one of the tasks is to try to identify whether the customer is already in Acumatica.

Thanks.

Comment: as srodinov said, you should save it in a specific format, which makes it easier to query it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default Acumatica has phone mask and it means that all phones in the system should be stored based on the specified mask, it will simplify your search.
Basically, from my standpoint you shouldn't have in the system phones which doesn't meet phone mask criteria. Also i'd suggest first of all update all phones data in the system and convert regarding phone mask.

Comment: Although I was initially looking for some kind of functions that I could use to preprocess the data before compare them in generic inquiry, such as using trim()  in SQL, then I realized I probably would have to use different way to do it, however, for my question, I think using mask is the best way, although it wouldn't work for different countries.

Answer (score 0):

One method I've seen used to keep a "local" db where you store replicas of the original info but using the phone numbers without spaces / "-" / other special characters.
You can query that database and you'll need a job to keep that db updated.
it kind of depends on the need you have.

Answer (score 0):

This is messy, but it would work... (agreed that a mask and consistent data would be best)
In the Relations of your Generic Inquiry, as an additional join in the Data Field Links on the Contact Table (where Phone1 is located), add "And" before a new line and enter a nested Replace formula in the Parent Field, then Equals, then another Replace formula in the Child field using your search string parameter.
Parent Field: 
`=Replace(Replace(Replace([Contact.Phone1],' ',''),'-',''),'ext','')`
Child Field:
`=Replace(Replace(Replace([Parameter1],' ',''),'-',''),'ext','')`

You can nest more Replaces inside there to replace parentheses or asterisks or anything else in your data.
That would require the search string to include the extension number, if you wanted to only look at numbers before the "ext", try using 
`Left([Contact.Phone1],InStr([Contact.Phone1],'ex')-1)`
insted of simply `[Contact.Phone1]` in the Parent field, then you wouldn't need the Replace for the string 'ext'...